# Sharepoint 2013 - manually start workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-manager

How do I automatically trigger this workflow from the submit button or choice field in SP 2013?

I have a series of workflows which are triggered by choice fields. If I set the workflows to **Start workflow Automatically when an item is changed** just overwrites my check boxes and initiated the workflow - how do I stop this? Example below:

[image]

Comment: your question is how to stop the assigned workflow? or how to trigger workflow manually?

Comment: No - how to automatically trigger the workflow when the form is submitted

Comment: Do you have any trouble with trigger a workflow when an item updated?

Comment: When the item is updated it trigger the workflow above disregarding the choice selection which is Form Handling  - I'm Finished...or Save for later

Comment: There is a JavaScript solution here https://gist.github.com/Aymkdn/3873181. I haven`t tried this but I know we can definitely do this.

Comment: Ok - I'll see how it goes. I have a number of workflows that are triggered in this same form and they all trigger again each time the form is changed. Perhaps I can adapt the script to work in this case as well.

Thanks Venkat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60746/discussion-between-venkat-konjeti-and-garvon-77).